# C++ recursively find minimum value of array

Tags: c++, recursion

I have an assignment for a c++ programming class to write a recursive function without the use of static variables, with the following prototype: 
int findmin(const int a[], int n);

My solution works (for very small arrays), however I think ~2^n complexity is excessive and could be improved.

Are there any improvements that could be made within the specified criteria that would make this more efficient?

```
int findmin(const int a[], int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return a[0];
    else
    {
        if(a[n-1] < findmin(a,(n-1)))
            return a[n-1];
      else
            return findmin(a,(n-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing the result of `findmin(a,(n-1));` instead of calling it again would help.

Comment: goto last index of array by recursion. Let last element be the minimum element and return it. At each unfolding recursion compare current index element with answer min and update if necessary.

Comment: @John3136  I'm surprised how much of a difference that made, it seems to be running at linear complexity now.

Comment: if `n` represents size, your algo is wrong (`a[0]` should not be valid when `n == 0`, else you don't check `a[n]`).

Comment: use a heap data struct. `findMin()` is `O(1)`

Comment: If you have a big array then the recursive way is bad , because it will i

Comment: exceed the stack size.So you'd have to increase the stack size which is not a good option when it comes to thinking a good alghorithm.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little silly to worry about efficiency, given that there is an obvious, non-recursive way to do it in O(n), one pass. There is even an STL algorithm std::min_element. But then, it's a silly assignment. FIrst be sure your solution is correct. When n==0, will a[0] be valid? Generally, such an `n` indicates the length of the array, not the lowest index.

To go from O[n^2] to O[n], be sure to compare each element only once. That implies not starting at the beginning of the array on every pass.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int findmin(const int a[], int n)
{
    assert(n>0);
    if(n == 1)  // See heyah.
        return a[0];
    else
    {
        return std::min(a[0], findmin(a + 1, n - 1));
    }
}
```

In for-real C++ code, if for some reason we were saddled with the old fashion function signature, we would do something like this:

```
int findmin(const int a[], int n) {
    if(n<=0) { throw std::length_error("findmin called on empty array");}
    return *std::min_element(a, a+n);
}
```

Comment: does this create a copy `O(n - 1)` times too?

Comment: @codekaizer. It creates no copies at all. The signature `const int a[]` is a holdover from C. We don't do that anymore. (C++ newbies should not even know about it yet, but that's another rant.) The array declaration `a[]` "decays" to a pointer, `int *a`.

Comment: @codekaizer - "Decay" sounds better than "type rot".

Comment: so if I search in the C++ specs the correct terminology is "type rot"? or "pointer decay"?

Comment: @codekaizer - Take your pick, but end up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying#1461449

Comment: @JiveDadson. I was thinking this solution in java. But in C++ it makes a whole lot difference what n indicates. In java array size is implicit but in C++ there is a whole different story. Impressive.detail catch.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore - Things are even better in C++ than in Java, provided one does things the easy way(s). Problem is, instructors teach students to write C code to be compiled with a C++ compiler. There are a lot of features in C++ that, for reasons of backward compatibility, are held over from C.

Comment: @JiveDadson can you suggest some links where I can study in detail what you saying above?

Answer (score 3):

You could do conditional operator `?:` to get rid of bunch `if else` statements, to make function cleaner. And instead of calling `findmin()` twice you could assign return value to variable inside of the statement, this is main advantage of this code vs. original one.

```
int findmin(const int a[], int n) {
   if (n == 0) // base case
      return a[0];

   return a[n] < (int min = findmin(a, n - 1)) ? a[n] : min;
}
```

This (`a[n] < (int min = findmin(a, n - 1)) ? a[n] : min;`) could be done using if statement as well:

```
if (a[n] < (int min = findmin (a, n - 1))
     return a[n];
else
     return min;
```

EDIT:
Per many reputable sources, this is O(n) time. O (n^2) would be if we are comparing each element with all the other elements.

Comment: @GRG This is homework question or assignment. Writing answer is not the ways of helping. Please guide him the way

Comment: This is good pseudocode for the right algorithm but it's got some typos.  I guess that's one way to make the asker think?

Comment: @BrijRajKishore I hope you are happy :)

Comment: @hegel5000 :) not anymore :)

Comment: That is not "the right algorithm". It is O[n^2], the evil from which we flee.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore - On some occasions, writing the answer might teach a student not to trust code from the internet. :-)

Comment: @BrijRajKishore  Sometimes an answer is  voted to +4, although it is incorrect and O[n^2].

Comment: @JiveDadson enlighten me how this algorithm is O(n^2)

Comment: OK guys I will delete this but explain to me how the is this `O(n^2)`?since it goes down recursively `n-1` elements and on its way back compares it to only one element? So in `a[n]` is `O (1)` and findmin(a, n - 1) is `O (n)`?

Comment: @BrijRajKishore   n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...1

Comment: It needs to increment a as it decrements n.  See the answer I posted.

Comment: What do you mean by increment a?

Comment: @GRC, it means `a[prev] < a[prev + 1]` should have been previously solved by the previous iteration. to make it `O(n)` you should have atleast "memoized" the previous results via Dynamic Programming.

Comment: It's the a+1 in `return std::min(a[0], findmin(a + 1, n - 1));`  or `return std::min(a[0], findmin(&(a[1]), n - 1));` if you're not into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: I still do not get it but OK, I believe you. For me this is like having a ball with numbers on staircase, you go down the staircase pick the ball on the bottom, than as you go upstairs you take a look at the ball at the stair you are on, if it is lesser, you drop ball from your hand and grub the one on that stair. So you are not going down the stairs again. You are not doing bubble sort and finding the next minimum.

Comment: in other words you are not comparing every ball with every other ball, you are comparing 1 ball (ball in you hand) with n - 1 other balls.

Comment: O(n^2) does not mean the steps number exactly n^2.  (n^2-n)/2 is O(n^2).  Figure it out.  Step through the algorithm and count. Turn that counting process into a mathematical series.  Have fun. I'm done.

Comment: Well lets say you have 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6. Recursively you go down 6 steps and grab 6. On your way back up you compare it to 2, grab 2, compare it to 1, grab 1, compare it to 7, 5, 3. That is 6 steps up, you do not care about 2 and 6 anymore. So that is 2 * n, not n + (n-1) ... 1.

Comment: And I do know that 0(n^2 - n)  means 0 (n^2).