# Big O() of recursive algorithm for finding minimum number

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have following code I was told `findmin` is O(n^2), but I cannot see it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int findmin(const int a[], int n);
int cnt = 0;

int main (void)
{
    int num = 100;
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

    int arr[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        arr[i] = std::rand() % num;

    findmin(arr, num);
    std::cout << cnt;
    return 0;
}

int findmin(const int a[], int n)
{
    cnt++;
    if(n == 0)
        return a[0];

    int min;
    return a[n] < (min = findmin(a, n - 1)) ? a[n] : min;
}
```

In my mind this algorithm goes down the last element, grabs it and comes back from recursion, compares it to an element and goes on, thus in my mind this is O(2*n).

In another way if we have array 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6, recursively we go down and grub 6. On our way up we find that 2 is smaller than 6 so we grub 2. Than we go up and compare it to 1 grub 1 and go up, comparing it to 7, 5, 3. So that is O(n). We are going through array n times. I would really appreciate if somebody can explain this to me.

Here is my source https://stackoverflow.com/a/50034011/5550963

Comment: is this code working? findmin(arr,100) will lead to index out of bound in a[n] isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `O(n)`. Whoever told you otherwise is mistaken.

Comment: Except that O(n^2) is a superset of O(n). So whoever told him was correct, just not as precise as possible.

Comment: @Ext3h Please could you elaborate.

Comment: That guy doesn't know what he's talking about. "That's it. I'm done." is their battle cry when faced with proof they're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`O(n) ⊂ O(n^2) ∧ t(n) ∈ O(n) => t(n) ∈ O(n^2)`

Yes, `findmin` is O(n), but it it is therefore also O(n^2).